# is every .keystore file built using keytool unique?

Tags: android, gradle, keystore, keytool, apksigner

I'm writing a python script to build and sign my android project using gradlew  ,
Everyone on the web is talking about how u can lose your generated key and therefor u can lose ability to update your published application.  my question is are every generated keys using keytool unique? 
and the signed apk using that key would easily be uploaded to google play store and every single app signed using that certain key will be considered as an update ?

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every key generated by keytool is unique.

For key management, you basically have a few options:

1. **Generate the app signing key** locally, keep it secure, and only use it when generating the release version of your app. Use a separate key for the debug versions of your app.
2. **Generate the app signing key locally, enroll in [App Signing by Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)** supplying your key to Google. During the enrollment, you will be prompted to created *another* key (called the upload key). You can use the upload key normally to sign the apps you upload to the Play Console, but make sure to keep the app signing in a safe place with strict ACLs. If you lose the upload key, you can always have it reset, so less critical.
3. The easiest solution (and the default in Play Console) is to **enroll in [App Signing by Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) and let Google generate the app signing key**. You are this way sure that you won't be accidentally losing or leaking it, and that it will be secure enough. Also, you'll only have one key to deal with: the upload key, which can be reset if you lose it.

I'd recommend the 3rd option (simplest, most secure), but some people prefer to keep a copy of the key with them and thus opt for the 2nd option. The 1st option is very risky as you seem to have already heard.

Comment: that's awesome bro . thanks a lot; , I'm trying to build a website like andromo.com
i wanted to know is there any way i can do 3rd option for other persons apps ?

Comment: As long as you're the person uploading the APK or AAB to the Play Console, yes, you can. Consider accepting the solution if that answers your question :)